# No correlation header in reply

Tags: java, spring-amqp

I have a problem using rabbitmq
Using rabbitmq in the latest version of springboot,
there is a method of convertSendAndReceive(..) ， The specific use is as follows

```
 Object object = rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(exchange,routekey, addFeatureReq); //交换器，路由器，报文，再其他项目中可以正常使用，这里报错
```

Under normal circumstances，I will get a return value，but，Now it's wrong，The error message is as follows

```
[17:36:29.760] INFO  com.xinda.config.RabbitTemplateConfig 33 confirm - 消息到达rabbitmq服务器
[17:36:31.967] WARN  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler 129 log - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed. org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1693) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:1037) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:997) [spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149) [amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104) [amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: No correlation header in reply
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.onMessage(RabbitTemplate.java:2559) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.lambda$setMessageListener$1(DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer.java:100) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
```

I don't know how to deal with this exception,Please help

Answer (score 0):

It means that the server side is not returning the `correlationId` property from the request in the reply. It is required.

If the server is a Spring application, this will generally happen automatically unless the application is doing something unusual.

Show your server-side code.